# Best option for isolation of output voltage from controller board?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, power-electronics, opto-isolator, isolation

So I have the following schematic:

[image]

I have a 400V output voltage which I have stepped down to less than 10V using resistor dividers in order to measure via DSPACE 1104 board(https://www.dspace.com/en/inc/home/products/hw/singbord/ds1104.cfm)

However I am being suggested to provide isolation between DSPACE input and my circuit output. What would be the most simplest and cost effective way of doing this? The voltage signal feedback needs to be faithful. I have looked into galvanically isolated amplifiers but they seem expensive.

Comment: Do you need galvanic isolation? Suggestions are one thing but what is the reality?

Comment: "Faithful" is not technically an engineering specification.  Could use an optocoupler, but may need to characterize it for any sort of accuracy.

Comment: @Andyaka Galvanic or optical anything is fine...I need to know if 1) Isolation is necessary, 2) What are my best options.

Comment: @Andyaka upon exploring further it seems to me optical is not suited for analog signals, in which case I assume galvanic isolation is my best option but it seems expensive.

Comment: **YOU** need to tell us whether isolation is necessary. I suspect it isn't but there's nothing in your circuit/question that confirms that.

Comment: @Andyaka I have never worked with hardware circuits before, this is my first board, so I don't know if this is something that is taken care of. Some sources say isolation is needed, others say it isn't. I am hoping people with some hands on experience will be able to give me some insight on what is the usual convention.